# Lookup Field and icon searching not working in salesforce 1 (mobile)

Tags: salesforce1-app, lookup, search

I have lookup field when click on the lookup it will show the account name and when i search its working in desktop/laptop. but the question is when i use mobile then click on the lookup and search particular account name it will not searching for salesforce 1. how to enable searching in lookup area.

Comment: its a custom VF page or standard  page

Comment: @tushar its Standard page

Comment: @cloudZigZag were you able to find the root cause? If yes, what's the fix for this issue?